# Listing directory with a question mark using JSch LS method

Tags: java, wildcard, sftp, jsch

I wrote a method that recursively lists children directories and their files using JSch `ChannelSftp.ls()`. It worked find until a directory with `?` was added to the SFTP server. Since `?` is a glob pattern, JSch doesn't work as I intended to. I've spent some time researching, but it seems like it's simply not possible to get info of a directory with a question mark (or * for the same reason). [Here's a post sharing the exact same problem as I have.](https://sourceforge.net/p/jsch/discussion/219651/thread/0148a05a/?limit=25)

Did anybody had the same issue and solved? For now, all I could do was replacing directory names.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indeed, when you specify a path with the last component containing `*` or `?`, like:

```
/actual/path/with/question?mark
```

... JSch considers the last component to be a filter/pattern for files. It strips the last component, lists the path `/actual/path/with`, and then filters the listed files only to those matching `question?mark` (usually returning only one entry, for the subfolder itself, instead of subfolder contents).

---

To workaround it, just add another pattern (`*`) to the path like:

```
/actual/path/with/question?mark/*
```

It makes JSch list the path `/actual/path/with/question?mark`, and then filter listed files to those matching `*` (which would be all of them).